# watch for dom element creation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

So, basically I have a plugin that I want called on an element if it is created in the dom,

E.g. let's say I have a plugin called domWatch that runs the function if the specified selector gets created inside the selector it was called on.

so:

```
$('#container').domWatch('.mySelector', function(element){
    $(element).myPlugin();
});

$('#container').append($('<div />', {class: 'mySelector'})); //the new element should now have the myPlugin plugin called on it.
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: LiveQuery is a way to do this, but if you are able to fire an event manually every time you append something to the dom, it might have better performance.

Comment: You can check something called [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events) or better [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_Mutation_Observers). However, it isn't implemented in all major browsers yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this clever hack: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/04/25/i-want-a-damnodeinserted/. It uses CSS3 animations to detect when an element was inserted into the DOM.

The problem with 'listening for when a DOM element is created' is the performance hit, so maybe you should consider a different approach to solve your problem.

I'm sure there are many, way simpler ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: Caution: Mutation events are deprecated, use Mutation Observer instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/) library that I developed for the exact same purpose (uses [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) internally). Usage:

```
$('#container').arrive('.mySelector', function(){
    $(this).myPlugin();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like [Live Query.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) Although this does involve continuous polling which does have a performance hit.

Here are some [demos](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/demos).

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting very modern browsers only you could check out *MutationObserver*, which is designed for that objective.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a job for the [delegated form of the `.on()` event](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   *descendant elements* that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or `document` if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   `document` element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.